# sharing more than one layer in R with Keras

Tags: r, neural-network, keras

In R with the package `keras`, a shared layer can be defined as

```
tweet_a <- layer_input(shape = c(140, 256))
tweet_b <- layer_input(shape = c(140, 256))

# This layer can take as input a matrix and will return a vector of size 64
shared_lstm <- layer_lstm(units = 64)

# When we reuse the same layer instance multiple times, the weights of the layer are also
# being reused (it is effectively *the same* layer)
encoded_a <- tweet_a %>% shared_lstm
encoded_b <- tweet_b %>% shared_lstm

# We can then concatenate the two vectors and add a logistic regression on top
predictions <- layer_concatenate(c(encoded_a, encoded_b), axis=-1) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

# We define a trainable model linking the tweet inputs to the predictions
model <- keras_model(inputs = c(tweet_a, tweet_b), outputs = predictions)
```

This can be found either at https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/functional_api.html or https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/articles/about_keras_models.html.

When you look at what `shared_lstm` is, you get `<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM>`, i.e. it is not a symbolic tensor. At least, it seems to be the problem when I try to share more than just a single layer with

```
shared_lstm <- layer_lstm(units = 64, return_sequences = TRUE) %>% layer_lstm(units = 64)
```

because I get the following error.

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
ValueError: Layer lstm_15 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.
Received type: <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM'>.
Full input: [<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM object at 0x000000016CF8A2B0>].
All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

The only way I can make it work is

```
shared_lstm1 <- layer_lstm(units = 64, return_sequences = TRUE)
shared_lstm2 <- layer_lstm(units = 64, return_sequences = TRUE)
shared_lstm3 <- layer_lstm(units = 64)

encoded_a <- tweet_a %>% shared_lstm1 %>% shared_lstm2 %>% shared_lstm3
encoded_b <- tweet_b %>% shared_lstm1 %>% shared_lstm2 %>% shared_lstm3
```

It can quickly become burdensome with a bigger structure... What is the right way to do that? Perhaps create a "layer node"?